# How to accept a POST request from the Node.js web application.js and return a response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I can't understand what the problem is, the essence of this request is to pass some data, call a function and send back the generated Json file, but this does not happen, instead the server does not return anything. What could be the problem? Please help me

Web part

```
clickOnRow: function(elem, whichScreen){
          this.clicks++          
          
          if(this.clicks === 1) {
            var self = this
            this.timer = setTimeout(function() {            
            console.log("одинарный");                 
              self.clicks = 0
            }, this.delay);
          } else{
             clearTimeout(this.timer);
             console.log("двойной");
             
             elem['whichScreen']  = whichScreen;    
             console.log(this.helper);
            //  this.nameOfMethod(elem);
             this.clicks = 0; 
            fetch('/currentDir1',{
                    method: 'POST',
                    mode: 'cors',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',                    
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(elem)                
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json())    
                    .then(json => this.helper = json)
                    .then(json =>  this.$emit("newvalue", json)) 
                    console.log("helper");
                    console.log(this.helper);
```

Server part

```
router.post('/currentDir1',(req, req) =>{  
    console.log("POST");
    
    let body = "";   
    let pathToFile = "";
    req.on("data", function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    
    req.on("end", function(currentData) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        currentData = JSON.parse(body);
        

        if(currentData.sizeOrType === "<папка>"){
            let dir = currentData.dir + currentData.fileName;
            // dir = "C:\\totalcmd";
            console.log(dir);                
            if(currentData.whichScreen){
                foo(dir, './data/firstScreen.json');
                pathToFile = './data/firstScreen.json';
                res.sendFile(path.resolve('./data/firstScreen.json'));
            }else{
                console.log('aaaa');
                Foo(dir, './data/secondScreen.json');
                pathToFile = './data/firstScreen.json';
                res.sendFile(path.resolve('./data/secondScreen.json'));
                
            }        
        }
    
        // res.json({ message: 'goodbye'})   
        res.json(path.resolve(pathToFile));     
    });
       
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(pathToFile));
})
```

Comment: the server keeps on loading / (and later gives a timeout) or shows a blank page ?

Comment: @YashKumarVerma the server is loading, but the fact is that this is not all my code, I posted only one post constipation

Comment: try debugging if the script is generating data to send or not, (console logging might help).

Comment: @YashKumarVerma   Do you mean from the server or web side?

Comment: @YashKumarVermavery strange, if you replace this entry with res.sendFile (), nothing will be sent and res.json() continues to send